# System.Web.Routing missing in Visual Web Developer

Tags: asp.net, routes, vwdexpress

I have installed Visual Web Developer 2008, the .net framework 3.5 but when i try to include System.Web.Routing intellisense can't find it and if i type it by hand it says it does not exist.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `System.Web.Routing.dll` assembly is part of .NET 3.5 Service Pack 1, so you'll have to install that if you haven't already (you may also have it if you installed the ASP.NET MVC beta). After that, you should be able to add it like any other .NET reference.

It shows up for me between System.Web.RegularExpressions and System.Web.Services on the ".NET" tab of the "Add Reference" dialog.

Answer (score 3):

You have to include a reference to the System.Web.Routing assembly in your project.

Comment: i could not find the file so could you explain in more detail?

Comment: Jester's answer explains when it was added to .NET. If you look at MSDN's system.web.routing page and look at the properties, you'll see that support was added with .NET 3.5 SP1.